# PowerPoint slide handouts exported to Word are either blank or incomplete. Can this be fixed? Are there alternatives?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I have 34 PowerPoint presentations ranging in size from 60-120 slides. I would like to publish these as handouts in Word so that I can manipulate them for handouts (I am a teacher).

However, when I try to "publish" them as Microsoft Word documents, I get a blank page (most often) or a few items will transfer but not all of them.

I want to make the conversion faster. I am open to using other software and to other ideas, but I **must** be able to edit the size/spacing of the information.

Answer (score -1):

Powerpoint-> word exports are slow because each picture is actually an embedded Powerpoint slide.
The easiest way (although quite time-consuming, but at least you'll be doing something instead of waiting for the word docs to render) is to do a Save-as on your powerpoint into .png files and then create a table big enough in word and drag the pictures into the right cells one at a time. 
Any software that'll automate this IME will royally screw the formatting if you even touch it.

In retrospect, a lot of Powerpoint purists would point out that giving slides out and commenting on them is quite inferior to a 'real' handout. Perhaps you may find it more effective to copy over your main points into Publisher and copy and tweak the text from the Powerpoint. That way you can probably save paper, and the handouts will be much more useful.

Comment: -1 because the question is about dealing with handouts, not slides.